# Skype profile picture is too blurry

Tags: windows-7, skype

Everytime I add a new skype image (even in the expected resolution - 480x480 pixels) **Skype** resizes it and the picture becames *blurred*.

Is there a way to fix it using **Windows 7**?

I read somewhere else that it is possible on Windows 8 but I don't have this OS right now.

**UPDATE:**

I upvoted Dave's answer but I would like to know if there are any other way of doing that without an external app.

Comment: Can you explain what is SO? Did you mean OS?

Comment: You are right. I meant OS.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a common issue with no direct fix, only a work around.

Download [Skype Portable 5.0](http://download.cnet.com/Skype-Portable/3000-2349_4-10972596.html) (or Google it if link dies.)
Quite Normal Skype.
Open Skype Portable.
Change picture.
Close Skype Portable.
Open Normal Skype with nice picture.

**Update**

Or, change the picture on the phone/tablet instead of the computer.

Comment: Can I trust this app? It does not seems to be an official App.

Comment: @douglaslps, Yes, but, I've changed the URL to a more familiar location, it now points to download.cnet.com - http://download.cnet.com/Skype-Portable/3000-2349_4-10972596.html

Comment: Maybe, if you have a smartphone, you could use the mobile app to change the picture.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me. Looks like this is a bug on Microsoft's side judging by this thread: http://community.skype.com/t5/Modern-Windows-from-Windows/My-Skype-profile-picture-is-too-blurry/td-p/1322141/page/7